# WP Plugin Custom Search

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I want to make costume search plugin for Wordpress 3.0.5. Please look at here first [HERE](http://ale.babonmultimedia.com/)

as you can see at that website there is a dropdown with Country, AREA, TYPE. and when we click find. the URL will produce URL GET like this `/?countryId=3&areaId=7&typeId=13`

The question is. how i can make a search plugin with that `$_GET`, or can somebody give me link reference how to that?

Comment: Questions posted to StackOverflow are licensed under Creative Commons; once you post them, they belong to the community.

Comment: @robert Maybe can be closed? since this is not needed anymore.

Comment: you are missing the pOint of SO. you don't close out questions or delete them if they are not needed. Others may have similar questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused what you are trying to do, a plugin? Or functionality that handles the 'find' results?

If you just want the functionality, create a PAGE, call it 'find' and then set the 'TEMPLATE' of that page to a custom template.  Create a custom page template by going via the wordpress codec

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Start by looking at the 'single.php' page, which is your standard wordpress template.
Once inside the template you use standard PHP to process the `$_GET` data and query your database.

Comment: Im doing a plugin. not template. the plugin is like WP Search Tag, WP Search Everything.